# How to get rid of tags before and after?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My current code is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://boost-heaven.com/sitemap_products_1.xml"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
urls = soup.find_all("url")
links = soup.find_all("loc")
title = soup.find_all("image:title")
time = soup.find_all("lastmod")
image = soup.find_all("image:loc")
i = 0
while i <= len(urls) - 1:
    for item in urls:
        if "products" in str(item):
            if "products" in str(links):
                print title[i - 1]
                print links[i]
                print time[i - 1]
                print image[i -1]
        i = i + 1
```

which returns:

```
<image:title>PIN SWG</image:title>
<loc>http://boost-heaven.com/products/swg-pin</loc>
<lastmod>2016-12-29T06:13:25Z</lastmod>
<image:loc>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1490/9704/products/swgpin2.jpgv=1479148164</image:loc>
<image:title>BEANIE</image:title>
<loc>http://boost-heaven.com/products/bg-beanie</loc>
<lastmod>2016-12-29T00:10:45Z</lastmod>
<image:loc>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1490/9704/products/redswg.jpgv=1482967350</image:loc>
<image:title>BG FLOORMAT</image:title>
<loc>http://boost-heaven.com/products/bg-floormat</loc>
<lastmod>2016-12-29T09:47:00Z</lastmod>
<image:loc>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1490/9704/products/floormatbg1.jpg?v=1482967260</image:loc>
<image:title>BG PABLO BURG</image:title>
<loc>http://boost-heaven.com/products/copy-of-bg-pablo-bn-t</loc>
<lastmod>2016-12-29T09:47:00Z</lastmod>
<image:loc>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1490/9704/products/burgundypabloe.jpg?v=1482878401</image:loc>
```

I'd like to get rid of the loc, lastmod, and other tags and just leave the text inside of them, but I'm not sure how to do so. I would also like to delete the "Z" within the time for lastmod and replace the "T" with " at ". Thank you.

Comment: use `image.get_text()` or `image.text` instead `str(image)` and you don't have to remove tags.

Comment: You're looping over the same elements in each of the inner loops. `links = soup.find_all("lastmod")` will get the same list of `lastmod` elements each time.

Comment: BTW, it's very confusing that you use the same variable `links` at all levels.

Comment: Why are you using `html.parser` for XML?

Comment: don't modify code in question ! you can append new code but always keep oryginal question and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get all `<url>` tags and search elements only inside every tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://boost-heaven.com/sitemap_products_1.xml"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# skip first element which has no data
all_urls = soup.find_all("url")[1:]

for url in all_urls:
    print('image:title:', url.find('image:title').get_text())
    print('        loc:', url.find('loc').get_text())
    # skip last char - "Z"
    print('    lastmod:', url.find('lastmod').get_text().replace("T", " at ")[:-1])
    print('  image:loc:', url.find('image:loc').get_text())
    print('---')
```

You can also use this two lines without `find()`

```
print('        loc:', url.loc.get_text())
print('    lastmod:', url.lastmod.get_text().replace("T", " at ")[:-1])
```

Instead of `get_text()` you can also use `text` - ie. `url.find('image:title').text`

Answer (score 0):

Try reinitializing each variable before they enter the loop, because in a loop it most probably takes the very first variable and loop it into each other item which are supposed to be passed into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loops are looping over all the same elements each time, not the elements related to the current image link from the outer loop. The final value of the variables comes from the last element of each list, so you get the same value each time.

You should be looping over the `<url>` elements, then finding the particular items within that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://boost-heaven.com/sitemap_products_1.xml"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for url in soup.find_all("url"):
    titlenode = url.find("image:title")
    if titlenode:
        title = titlenode.text
        loc = url.find("loc").text
        lastmod = url.find("lastmod").text
        imageloc = url.find("image:loc").text
        print title + "\n" + loc + "\n" + lastmod + "\n" + imageloc
```

Comment: title = url.find("image:title").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I get the same Error.

Comment: I test it and find out the 'xml' parser will raise the problem. 'lxml' parser works fine.

Comment: you have to skip first `<url>` which has no data.

Comment: I've added a check to see if the `<url>` contains an `<image:title>` node. It then assumes that it will have all the other nodes. A more bullet-proof program would check each node before trying to get its text.